# Is there a name for this statistic? What type of distances it is measuring between two data sets?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I am not a statistician and I saw a paper in computational PDE, someone argued his error bound for PDE is a good indicator of the PDE's numerical approximation's true error's spatial distribution by using the following way: he had two data sets $\{e\}_{i=1}^N$ and $\{\eta\}_{i=1}^N$ ($i$ is the index of the mesh), and he computed something like this:
$$
\mu = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^N \left(\frac{e_i}{\sum_{i=1}^N e_i} - 
\frac{\eta_i}{\sum_{i=1}^N \eta_i}\right)^2}
$$
he said if this quantity is small(kinda ambiguous), then $\eta_i$ is somewhat a nice approximation to $e_i$ spatially(i.e. $\eta_1$ is near $e_1$, something like that), but he didn't give any name of this statistic and what test he was trying to perform. I wonder what does this $\mu$ is trying to measure?

Thanks in advance, and I am no expert in this, so I may have chosen the wrong tag, correct me if I were wrong.

Comment: Could you indicate how a single number like $\mu$ is presumed capable of expressing an entire "spatial distribution"?  One would expect an error map rather than a single value.

Comment: If all the $e_i$ and $\eta_i$ are nonnegative, then dividing by $\sum_i e_i$ and $\sum_i \eta_i$ converts the data into probability mass functions of a discrete random variable that takes on $N$ values.  Using absolute values instead of squares of the differences would make that sum the statistical distance between two categorical distributions (maybe off by factor of 2?) and perhaps squares are being used for the same reason that everyone computes the variance instead of the mean absolute deviation?

Comment: @whuber No, $\mu$ sure can not. I asked the author, the author said it measures "how similar these two data sets are, sequentially", I have no idea as well.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Thanks, sorry for the late reply, I am inclined to believe your comment is the answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like just the Euclidean distance between two points in $N$-space, where the points have been "normalized" by dividing by $\sum e_i$ and $\sum \eta_i$, respectively.  Not sure about the value of that "normalization"; what if the sums are very small relative to the typical $|e_i|$ and/or $|\eta_i|$, or even negative?  Maybe if the normalization was by the (Euclidean) length of the vector instead...

I completely agree with @whuber; this number hardly reflects a "spatial distribution."

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the late acceptance, $e_i$ and $\eta_i$ are positive for all $i$. The normalization is weird indeed.